# Error with checkkey(usertest) function not returning 1 or 0 with count in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Output is as follows:

> WELCOME, NEW USER, PLEASE ENTER A VALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD
> Enter username: sus
> error no valid value returned
> Error, unknown exception in boolean

this appears to be from the checkkey function

```
def checkkey(usertest):
    cursor.execute("select count(username) from users where username='{}';".format(usertest))
    if cursor.fetchone()==1:
        return True
    elif cursor.fetchone()==0:
        return False
    else:
        print("error no valid value returned")
        return False
```

Why is it not returning 1 or 0?

Comment: Try doing `count = cursor.fetchone();print(type(count), repr(count))` to see what you are getting.

Comment: where am i supposed to enter that? i used it instead of count.execute("...,, and it adds another statement <class 'NoneType'> None and still prints the other two error statements

Comment: After you call `execute`, before the `if`; you can comment out or delete the if/elif/else block temporarily as they won;t work while this line is in place.

Comment: > WELCOME, NEW USER, PLEASE ENTER A VALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD
> Enter username: asas
> <class 'tuple'> (0,)

For reference its supposed to return true or false

Comment: What that output is telling you is that your assumption that `fetchone()` will return an `int` is incorrect.  In fact it returns a `tuple` - `(0,)` in this case - some you need to extract the value by doing `cursor.fetchone()[0]`.  `fetchone()` can only be called once per query, so you should assign the result to a variable - `count = cursor.fetchone()` and use the variable in your `if/elif` checks.